# Check whether an object was created inside a loop or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops

is there any way in Objective-C to check whether an Object has been created inside a loop (while, for)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do this for? Why does it matter?

Comment: For which kind of data you want to check? Is it type of string, int or array? Specify more then i can answer well.

Comment: Niray, not a special type. It's a custom class which inherits from NSObject

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *obj = nil;

while()
 {
 //Create object
   obj = [[NSString alloc] init];

}

//check obj is nil or not

if(nil == obj)
{
// obj not created
}
```

Comment: Anil, it wasn't meant to be like this. I want to check within the init Method of, for example "mySuperCoolClass". And, it's without knowing if the object has been created inside a loop or not. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but for an accurate answer can you tell us what the object is and when it is declared? Can you post the code you have?

```
int x=0;
while (x<3) {
    NSString *i = @"hello world";
    x++;
}

NSLog(@"i is %@", i) // i is only declared inside the while loop so not available here
```

Alternatively,

```
int x=0;
NSString *i;
while (x<3) {
    i = @"hello world";
    x++;
}
NSLog(@"i is %@", i); // i is declared beforehand outside the while loop so is available here
```

If you then need to act on whether it's been created or not use Anil's answer but it's the scope that's important here

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can know if it was created in a loop, but because you are writing the code where the object will be created in a loop you could call a special init method...

```
SpecialClass * obj = [[SpecialClass alloc] init];

while (isTrue)
{
     SpecialClass * loopObj = [[SpecialClass alloc] initCreatedByLoop];
     // Do whats needed
}
```

and in your SpecialClass you create a specific initialiser...

```
@implementation SpecialClass

-(id)initCreatedByLoop {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // What ever you want to do
    }

    return self;
}
```